# Retrieving a column from a left join subquery in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am getting an error `[Error] Execution (12: 25): ORA-00904: "N"."PORT_AID": invalid identifier` after I added a left outer join `EDW_SPLITTER_NT_PORT` to my `spl` sub query. How can i get my query to work? It is getting the `N.PORT_AID` from the `n` subquery and its not reaching it in the spl? Should i change my left join `EDW_SPLITTER_NT_PORT` in the `spl` subquery and join it instead to the `n` subquery at the bottom.

`EDW_SPLITTER` AND `EDW_SPLITTER_NT_PORT` are related to each other so thats why I added the left join to that table. Any suggestions?

```
Select spl.splitter_addr AS splitter_address,
          spl.splitter_port,
          spl_port_status
          from (
   SELECT splitter.splitter_addr AS splitter_address,
          splitter.splitter_port,
          CASE
             WHEN splitter.SPLITTER_PORT_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
             THEN
                CASE
                   WHEN n.PORT_AID IS NULL THEN 'INACTIVE'
                   ELSE 'ACTIVE'
                END
             ELSE --follow through with whatever splitter_port_status other than active remains:
                DECODE (splitter.splitter_port_status,
                        'IN-ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE',
                        splitter.splitter_port_status)
          END
             AS splitter_port_status

     FROM ls2.edw_splitter@WBCMLS1P.sbc.com splitter 
                          left outer join EDW_SPLITTER_NT_PORT nt
    --  ON     splitter.splitter_addr = nt.splitter_addr
    ON     splitter.eid = nt.eid
                          AND splitter.rack = nt.rack
                          AND splitter.shelf = nt.shelf
                          AND splitter.card = nt.card
                          AND splitter.port = nt.port)  spl


          LEFT OUTER JOIN
          (SELECT a.eid,
                  a.location_id,
                  o.rack,
                  o.shelf,
                  TO_NUMBER (SUBSTR (card, -2, 2)) AS slot,
                  o.port,
                  o.ont,
                  o.port_aid,
                  o.ont_type
             FROM ls2.actl73x0@WBCMLS1P.sbc.com a
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN ls2.ACTL73XX_ONT@WBCMLS1P.sbc.com o
                     ON a.eid = o.eid
           UNION ALL
           SELECT b.eid,
                  b.location_id,
                  1 rack,
                  1 shelf,
                  bo.card AS slot,
                  bo.port,
                  bo.ont,
                  REPLACE (bo.ont_aid, 'ONT', 'ONT-1-1') AS port_aid,
                  bo.ont_type
             FROM ls2.blm@WBCMLS1P.sbc.com b
                  LEFT OUTER JOIN ls2.blm_ont@WBCMLS1P.sbc.com bo
                     ON b.eid = bo.eid) n
             ON     spl.eid = n.eid
                AND n.rack = spl.rack
                AND n.shelf = spl.shelf
                AND n.slot = spl.slot
                AND n.port = spl.port
                AND n.ont = spl.ont
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you're saying that the `PORT_AID` column comes from the n subquery. However, you're trying to use it inside the spl subquery, which is out of scope for the n subquery. You'd have to add further joins in the spl subquery in order to expose that column in the subquery, or you could leave it and reference it in the outer query.

Also, the `splitter` alias you're using in the outer select isn't valid.

Comment: yes you read it correctly that is what i want to do, I need the port_AID column in the `spl` subquery. yes your right the outer select needs to have `spl` reference instead of `splitter`, but that is the least of my concern.

Comment: So all you need to do is move the case statement from the spl subquery to the outer query. You'll have to make sure all the relevant columns are in the select lists of the joined subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery `spl`:

```
SELECT splitter.splitter_addr AS splitter_address,
    splitter.splitter_port,
    CASE 
        WHEN splitter.SPLITTER_PORT_STATUS = 'ACTIVE'
            THEN CASE 
                    WHEN n.PORT_AID IS NULL
                        THEN 'INACTIVE'
                    ELSE 'ACTIVE'
                    END
        ELSE --follow through with whatever splitter_port_status other than active remains:
            DECODE(splitter.splitter_port_status, 'IN-ACTIVE', 'INACTIVE', splitter.splitter_port_status)
        END AS splitter_port_status
FROM ls2.edw_splitter@WBCMLS1P.sbc.com splitter
LEFT JOIN EDW_SPLITTER_NT_PORT nt
    --  ON     splitter.splitter_addr = nt.splitter_addr
    ON splitter.eid = nt.eid
        AND splitter.rack = nt.rack
        AND splitter.shelf = nt.shelf
        AND splitter.card = nt.card
        AND splitter.port = nt.port
```

makes reference to `n.PORT_AID` but there is no derived table `n` in this subquery. It has no idea what you are talking about when you say `n.PORT_AID` here.

Comment: yes `n.port_aid` is out of scope in the `spl` just wondering how i can make it in scope should i drop the spl parenthesis and the outer select and just do an left outer join follow by another left outer join